# How to remove common elements between two lists of strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to Haskell. I want to compare two lists of strings and remove the common elements between the lists and return a new list with unique elements.

Below is the code that I have:

```
Prelude Data.List> let list_1 = ["apple", "orange", "apple"]
Prelude Data.List> let list_2 = ["apple"]
Prelude Data.List> let removeCommonWords  xs ys = filter (\x -> x `elem` ys) xs
Prelude Data.List> removeCommonWords list_1 list_2
```

output of the above code:

```
["apple","apple"]
```

Currently, the `filter` function is filtering the common words and returning a new list that contains the common words. However, I want it to return a new list that contains the unique words. I think I will need a new regex expression for the filter function.

Expected output:

```
["orange"]
```

I also attempted the following:

```
Prelude Data.List> let removeCommonWords  xs ys = filter (\x -> x `elem` ys) xs
Prelude Data.List> remove ["orange", "apple", "apple"] "apple"
```

The output of the above code is:

```
["orange"]
```

However, I want to compare two lists of strings - not a list and string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that is what you want

```
let removeCommonWords  xs ys = filter (\x -> not (x `elem` ys)) xs
```

**Edit**:
You can also use `notElem` directly as:

```
let removeCommonWords  xs ys = filter (\x -> x `notElem` ys) xs
```

Comment: There's also the `notElem` function.

Answer (score 2):

Within Data.List there are three functions that do what you're trying to achieve with filters.

`intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` does exactly what `removeCommonWords` does in your code. `intersect list_1 list_2` will produce `["apple","apple"]`.

`nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` combined with `(\\) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` will give you the opposite. `nub list_1 \\ nub list_2` will produce `["orange"]`.

Look up these functions on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5C%5C) for more details :)